# Android custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a galaxy tab 10.1 connected (by Bluetooth) to a hardware keyboard. What I couldn't figure out was how to use custom shortcuts to do specific task the same way I do it on my pc.

For instance, say I type `Ctrl+e` on the keyboard, then the application menu will be opened.

I searched the android market, xda-developers site, stackoveflow and the net for an answer but couldn't find an answer. I did not even find out if rooting was required for this :(

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: are you rooted?

Comment: yes I am. Why?.

Comment: Then I would follow the process dissassembler posted. I did this with my bt keyboard, and it worked like a charm :) I might have another resource on it, if I find it, I'll give you another answer

Answer (score 1):

I searched around a bit, and I think what you want are key mappings for your Bluetooth keyboard. I found [this](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=159538) on MobileRead.

It looks like what you want to do is possible, but it may require a bit of work. I'm getting a bluetooth keyboard, so I may end up trying this myself.

As always, remember to backup anything important in case you run into some problems. I hope this helps. :)